# Float left div inside center container

Tags: html, css

All...

I want to ask very basic CSS. Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/fzJ8X/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="item">
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item">
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: #F00 5px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}

.overlay {
    border: #00F 5px solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}

.item img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    display: block;
}
```

I have three boxes inside container with style text-align:center. Now all boxes centered like I want, but how to all boxes in float left? like screenshot below :

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt4be.jpg)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Uploaded same images..

Comment: Your fiddle link points to the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

JS iddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZst7/3/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: #F00 5px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.overlay {
    border: #00F 5px solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}

.item img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="container">   
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 430px;">    
            <div class="item">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="item">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much P5Coder, and also thank you to all who have answered my question.... :)

Comment: Welcome. Please see that I have updated the answer to accommodate the changes for the spaces you need between the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

add float:left; to the code

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: #F00 5px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fzJ8X/12/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much to do. 
Add **float:left;** to .item{} as below.

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: #F00 5px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}
```

Check the fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themlas/7zUfk/)